# How to remove a audio output device

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, input-devices, output

I installed droidcam to enable video through phone but it also installed some audio input/output devices in my system which I want to remove.

Droidcam added the audio devices through this script, can someone help me blacklist those devices?

```
#!/bin/bash
#
etc_modules() {
    echo "Adding driver to /etc/modules"
    cp /etc/modules /tmp/etc_modules_bak
    prevperm=`stat -c %a /etc/modules`
    chmod 666 /etc/modules
    [[ ! $(egrep "^snd-aloop$" /etc/modules) ]] && echo "snd-aloop" >> /etc/modules
    chmod $prevperm /etc/modules
}

if [ ! -s "/etc/modprobe.d/droidcam.conf" ]
then
    echo "Error: droidcam not installed"
    exit 1
fi

echo "Loading Loopback device"
modprobe snd-aloop || exit 1

LOOPBACK_CARD_ID=$(grep -F "[Loopback" < /proc/asound/cards | awk '{print $1}')
if [[ ! $(echo "$LOOPBACK_CARD_ID" | grep -E "^[0-9]$") ]]
then
    echo "Error: Could not determine Loopback card number"
    exit 1
fi
grep -v "snd-aloop" < /etc/modprobe.d/droidcam.conf > /tmp/modprobe.d_droidcam.conf
echo "options snd-aloop index=$LOOPBACK_CARD_ID" >> /tmp/modprobe.d_droidcam.conf
mv /tmp/modprobe.d_droidcam.conf /etc/modprobe.d/droidcam.conf

if [ -f "/etc/modules-load.d/droidcam.conf" ]
then
    echo "snd-aloop" >> /etc/modules-load.d/droidcam.conf
elif [ -e "/etc/modules" ]; then
    etc_modules
else
    echo "Warning: Unknown distro. Sound card may not load after a reboot."
fi
echo "Done"
echo "Use 'pacmd load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:Loopback,1,0' to load the card into PulseAudio while droidcam is running"
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same problem, it helped me to remove the `snd-aloop` line from the  `/etc/modules-load.d/droidcam.conf` file to avoid loading the loopback module on startup. After a reboot, the devices are gone.

Comment: i tried uninstalling the way it said on your website. and after restart the devices were gone.

Comment: I have a problem with audio device built into one of my monitors. I NEVER want to use it.  How can I remove it?